# Radio checked on database boolean value

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have the following here

[image]

[image]

a boolean value is stored in the database so I want it so if yes or no is checked the radio button is checked and represents the boolean value within the database.

How would I go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Use handlebars [`if`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#conditionals) and [`unless`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#unless) block helpers:

```
<input id="yes" type="radio" {{#if attendedRehersal}}checked{{/if}} ?>
<label for="yes">Yes</label>


<input id="no" type="radio" {{#unless attendedRehersal}}checked{{/unless}} ?>
<label for="no">No</label>
```

where `attendedRehersal` is the boolean field sent to your view:

```
{
    attendedRehersal: true // false
}
```

Comment: Also attended_rehersal is stored as attendedRehersal one word, no underscore.

Comment: So I'm now using the code above https://gyazo.com/8313484746a1526bc2adc21d1400d486 and is set to true but the attendedRehersal  no radio is being checked

Comment: Please show me what data exactly do you respond to the view, then I can help you render it. No point in my guessing for a third time.

Comment: On the side: the code you posted uses the same `id` attribute's valuetwice which is not valid.